# Increase size of encrypted swap

Tags: boot, swap, cryptswap

Ubuntu 18.04 is by default creating a random encrypted swap during each boot using dm-crypt/Swap encryption. For me, this is creating a 1gb swap but I cannot find where to increase the size of the swap it creates on each boot. How can we increase the swap size allocated during each boot? I do not want to switch to a static swapfile. There is no `/swapfile` or partition.

This appears to be a new feature where the swap is dynamically created each time the system boots. How can I increase it?

from **/etc/crypttab**:

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=1e092df8-5c37-4409-8ac8-361402244f69 none luks,discard
cryptswap1 UUID=aba1b825-a77b-4384-a40f-fdc6fdaaced0 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

from **/etc/fstab**:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

```
# swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-3                               partition   1003004 601088  -2
```

[image: htop]

gparted does not show any swap partition. This is the only drive.

[image: gparted]

In an answer here, it is suggested to do:

```
sudo swapoff -a  
sudo cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size (in sectors)  
sudo mkswap /dev/cryptswap1  
sudo swapon -a
```

So I run: `cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 7812500`. This results in the error: `Device /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 is too small.`

So I try: `cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 --size 7812500`

This does not produce an error but `parted --list; fdisk -l` shows no change:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 979.5 MiB, 1027080192 bytes, 2006016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

and trying to again run `cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 7812500` produces `Device /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 is too small.`

I have also tried: `resize2fs /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 -s 4G` which produced:

```
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

```
# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                   7:0    0  54.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1279
loop1                   7:1    0  89.1M  1 loop  /snap/core/8213
loop2                   7:2    0  89.1M  1 loop  /snap/core/8268
loop3                   7:3    0 497.4M  1 loop  /snap/wickrme/246
loop4                   7:4    0 497.2M  1 loop  /snap/wickrme/247
loop5                   7:5    0  54.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1288
nvme0n1               259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 464.6G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   253:0    0 464.6G  0 crypt 
    ├─mint--vg-root   253:1    0 463.6G  0 lvm   /
    └─mint--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1    253:3    0 979.5M  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

Comment: What is the device type?  (plain, luks, etc.)

Comment: The drive is luks encrypted.

Comment: Can we see the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: Added it. It appears I had a misconception. I didn't realize that gparted doesn't deal with LVM. I think I need to shrink my root LVM to give more room for my cryptswap but I don't have a flash drive on hand to boot to. I don't think the root vol can be shrunk "Live"

Comment: I updated the answer based on the error you got. Also, you didn't allow for the size of the header in your attempted resizing of mint--vg-swap_1 (2MiB). mint--vg-swap_1 needs to be 2MiB larger than cryptswap (so cryptswap wouldn't fit in there). I don't think you can use that resize command on the container. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo swapoff -a  
sudo cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size (in sectors)  
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1  
sudo swapon -a
```

If --size is left out, it will use the whole device.

**UPDATE** - Based on feedback.  **Reboot** and make sure mint--vg-swap_1 is still 980M.
**IF IT IS**, do the steps below.  --  Try manually increasing the size of the container first (I don't think that should have been necessary).  Your comment says you are trying to make the swap 4G (+3G), so:

```
sudo swapoff -a  
sudo lvresize -L+3G /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1
sudo cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 7812500
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1  
sudo swapon -a
```

On the other hand, if mint--vg-swap_1 **is now 4G**, then run this (allow for the size of the header):

```
sudo swapoff -a  
sudo cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 7808404   
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1  
sudo swapon -a
```

[Reference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cryptsetup.8.html)

Comment: Will this persist between boots? How do I calculate the sectors? I assume I need to print the current sector size and divide by total desired size?

Comment: The manual says `--size, -b <number of 512 byte sectors>` so I tried `cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 7812500` which resulted in `Device /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 is too small.`

Comment: Added attempt info to question.

Comment: Using cyrptsetup resize will persist on boot as long as you increased the swap size, rather than decreasing it.  (Yes, it's weird.)

Comment: I updated the answer based on the feedback you added to the question.

Comment: **DO NOT `lvresize` the root partition without `--resizefs` option beforehand**. When shrinking this will corrupt the filesystem!

Comment: When trying to use this method to increase my swap size I get `Device cryptswap1 is not active.` when running `sudo cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 31457280` (I want to increase my swap by 15G and if my understanding is correct that means I need to have 31457280 * 512 byte sectors as size)

I tried running `sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1` as well, but that gave me `sudo cryptsetup resize cryptswap1 --size 31457280`

Answer (score 11):

**This answer is based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**

```
lslbk
   # └─sda6                  8:6    0 464,6G  0 part  
   #   └─sda6_crypt        253:0    0 464,5G  0 crypt 
   #     ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 463,6G  0 lvm   /
   #     └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

One thing that was not addressed before is, that, in order to **INCREASE** the lvm swap size, the lvm root size has to be **DECREASED** first!

(At least when `lsblk` (like above) shows that root + swap make up the whole encrypted device.)

---

#### **TL;DR (But backup important data!)**

Here we decrease root -40G AND increase swap +40G:

```bash
# Boot Ubuntu Live/Flash/"Try Ubuntu" AND open terminal
# Run subsequent commands as superuser
sudo -i
    # `sudo`    => Execute a command as another user.
    # `sudo -i [-u user]` => Run an interactive session with substitute user, default is root.
    # `sudo [-u user] command` => Run a command with a substitute user, default is root.

# Encrypted device should NOT be unlocked
lsblk # => list block devices
    # └─sda6 => no `crypt`/`lvm``
```

```bash
# Unlock encrypted device
cryptsetup open /dev/sda6 crypt # Enter passphrase
    # `cryptsetup` => Manage dm-crypt + LUKS encrypted volumes.
    # `cryptsetup open <device> <name>` => Opens encrypted lv as <name>

# Get logical volume identifiers
lsblk
    # └─sda6                  8:6    0 464,6G  0 part
    #   └─sda6_crypt        253:0    0 464,5G  0 crypt
    #     ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 463,6G  0 lvm   /
    #     └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]

# Shrink logical root volume AND filesystem
lvresize --verbose --resizefs -L -40G /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
    # `lvresize` <volume> => resize a logical volume
    #   --verbose  => Give more info.
    #   --resizefs => Resize filesystem AND LV with fsadm(8).
    #   -L         => Specifies the new size of the LV, 
    #                 +/- add/subtracts to/from current size, g|G is GiB.

# Check filesystem of logical root volume for errors
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
    # `e2fsck`<fs-path> => Check a Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 file system
    #   -f => Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

# Increase swapsize
lvresize --verbose -L +40G /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1
```

**After rebooting**, Ubuntu should start normally, swap should be adjusted size:

```
lslbk
    # └─sda6                  8:6    0 464,6G  0 part  
    #   └─sda6_crypt        253:0    0 464,5G  0 crypt 
    #     ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 423,6G  0 lvm   /
    #     └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0    41G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

**If the system monitor still only has the initial 1G** it is necessary to rewrite the logical swap device:

```
swapon --show
    # NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
    # /dev/dm-2 partition 976M   0B   -2

swapoff -v /dev/dm-2
    # swapoff /dev/dm-2

mkswap /dev/dm-2
    # mkswap: /dev/dm-2: warning: wiping old swap signature.
    # Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 41 GiB (43973079040 bytes)
    # no label, UUID=...

swapon -a
    # Turn on swapspace
```

Comment: I tried to increase my swap size using this, however I am getting
`Cannot use device /dev/sda6 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).`
which I imagine is because I only have one device and I am already using it. What would be some possible solutions?

Comment: @Stromwerk 1. If you ask for advice on a failed command obviously we exactly need to know which command you are talking about. 2. If it is `lvresize` `/dev/sda6` seems wrong since this answer is for an encrypted swap that should reside under `/dev/mapper/`. 3. In general resizing should be done from a Linux live disk, not from the system you want to change, then non `/dev/sdaX` should be  mounted. 4. Ask yourself why `sda6` is mounted. 5. Maybe search for how to unmount an `sdaX` device.

Comment: The command is `lvresize --verbose --resizefs -L -15G /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` (I have it as -15G as I only want to change my swap size by that much). I understand now the solution is most likely to use a Linux live disk, which I can't easily obtain at the moment. Thank you