# Encrypted partitions (LUKS) with login password + hibernate

Tags: login, encryption, swap, hibernate, luks

on my company laptop I have Windows 11, that has encrypted disk, working hibernate, at I need to provide password just once at log-in. I would like to have same on my personal laptop with Ubuntu. RN I have Ubuntu 20.04. with some mess in it, so I would like to do clean install of Ubuntu 22.04. and want to know what is best and easiest way to encrypt partitions (LUKS, or maybe something else?) that will allow me to skip GRUB, and would unlock disk/partitions at log-in with login password. At the same time I would need / require a working hibernate. Note that I don't use SWAP file but partition.

RN I use this configuration for hibernation:
https://gist.github.com/Mlocik97/5936fa55d4971f05c6a1c0fb10c4c9bb
aka I set `sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` file with content:

```
[Enable hibernate in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

But it works because I don't have SWAP encrypted. I set resume param like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/nvme0n1p3"` in `/etc/default/grub` file, but now when I turn on computer, GRUB menu shows, even tho Ubuntu is only system on my personal laptop, and I would like to skip that step.

I tried in VMs (QEMU/KVM) to install Ubuntu 22.04. with encrypted virtual disk (LUKS), that installer gave me as option on LVM partitions, but when I did it, I needed to give it password twice, once for unlocking disk/partitions, and second time at login, I think it's annoying and would like if I could give it password just once.

So I'm solving two problems, making hibernate works with encrypted SWAP, and unlock of partitions works with login password. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: With the help of TPM chip, encryption password input (manual) can be avoided. Try this out:

https://run.tournament.org.il/ubuntu-20-04-and-tpm2-encrypted-system-disk/

Comment: Thanks @PrakashS I will test it in VMs and see if it works, if yes, I will try it on bare-metal (my personal laptop hardware)

Comment: Here is [another How to use TPM2 with LUKS](https://micwan88.github.io/linux/ubuntu/luks/tpm/encryption/2021/05/03/auto-unlock-luks-volume-by-tpm2.html).

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, please accept it by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is for enabling hibernate with an encrypted swap partition. This answer does not deal with using TPM or other means of bypassing the LUKS password prompt.

## Hibernate with LUKs Encrypted Swap Partition

### Outline and References

**First** Increase swap partition:

[Changing Swap size on encrypted LVM? (kubuntu 20.04 installation)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240217/changing-swap-size-on-encrypted-lvm-kubuntu-20-04-installation/1412398#1412398)

**Second** Enable hibernate

[Increase size of encrypted swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193618/increase-size-of-encrypted-swap)
https://gist.github.com/tjvr/f82004565139a5b13031af1ce5a50a02

### 1. Decrease root and increase swap partitions

#### Introduction

Install Ubuntu in your laptop using the default installation process. Choose LUKS (and LVM) under advanced option. Test the system to make sure everything works.

My laptop had 4GB RAM and a 1GB encrypted swap partition from the installation process. I used the formula of:

**New Swap Partition Size = Size of RAM + Sqrt(Size of RAM)**

So I needed a 6GB swap. That is, I needed to add 5GB to the existing swap partition.

#### The actual process

**Note: The partition numbers, logical volume names etc. are from a clean default installation (with encryption) of Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop with no other OS. YMMV.**

Boot from the Ubuntu Live Installation USB and use the "Try Ubuntu" option.

Open a terminal and run subsequent commands as superuser

```
sudo su
```

The encrypted device should NOT be unlocked. Verify with:

```
lsblk
```

The output should not have any `crypt` or `lvm`.

Unlock encrypted device

```
cryptsetup open /dev/sda4 crypt
```

Enter the LUKS passphrase when prompted.

Get the logical volume identifiers

```
lsblk

# └─sda4                  8:6    0 464,6G  0 part
#   └─sda4_crypt        253:0    0 464,5G  0 crypt
#     ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 463,6G  0 lvm   /
#     └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

Shrink logical root volume AND filesystem.

```
lvresize --verbose --resizefs -L -5G /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root

# `lvresize` <volume> => resize a logical volume
#   --verbose  => Give more info.
#   --resizefs => Resize filesystem AND LV with fsadm(8).
#   -L         => Specifies the new size of the LV, 
#                 +/- add/subtracts to/from current size, g|G is GiB.
```

Check filesystem of logical root volume for errors

```
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root

# `e2fsck`<fs-path> => Check a Linux ext2/ext3/ext4 file system
#   -f => Force checking even if the file system seems clean.
```

Increase swapsize

```
lvresize --verbose -L +5G /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1
```

close the terminal and reboot to the internal LUKS encrypted drive.

**The command `free` shows the old swap size.**

Source: [Increase size of encrypted swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193618/increase-size-of-encrypted-swap)

The following commands in the terminal should fix this:

```
sudo swapoff -a  
sudo cryptsetup resize vgubuntu-swap_1
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 
sudo swapon -a
```

Use the `free` command again to verify that you have the swap size you need.

### 2. Enable Hibernate to Swap

**Note: I didn't have to make any changes to (or create) the file** `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` **as mentioned in the question.**

Edit the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and add:

```
RESUME=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1
```

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` to make the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1"
```

The next two command will update intramfs and grub respectively:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

To test run:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

If all goes well your laptop should hibernate.

Hope this helps