# How to get GNOME to recognize hibernate and make it available from dropdown menu and as a power button otpion?

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

Now that I managed to [extend swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419913/increasing-the-size-of-swap-partition-volume-does-not-increase-the-size-of-swap/1419917) and enable hibernation, I'd like hibernate to be available from the menu and as an action under the power button.

I tried assigning hibernate through gsettings

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action hibernate
```

but it only brings up an interactive shutdown menu instead.

I have also tried looking for a GNOME extension to make hibernate visible in the menu. However, the only extension compatible with my GNOME (42.2) is [Hibernate Status Button by p91paul](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/755/hibernate-status-button/) which doesn't seem to have any effect.

**How to enable hibernation with the power button and in the GNOME menu on Ubuntu 22.04?**

I can successfully hibernate issuing

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

so the mechanism is working. I only need the UI options.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have the first half of the solution. It is possible to surface hibernate in the menu.

The extension is fine but [requires additional steps](https://support.system76.com/articles/enable-hibernation/):

> NOTE: Pop!OS and Ubuntu require a file at
> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
>
> To create this file, run:
>
> sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.pkla
>
> Then copy these contents into the newly created file:

```
[Enable hibernate in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

**The question of how to make the power button hibernate remains.**

Comment: With your solution Dawn Terminal, all you then have to do is go to Gnome Settings->Power and select Hibernate from the Power Button Behaviour drop-down. Nice One :-D

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions, I tried both of them, always at least one of them is working.

## Solution 1

You can use [Hibernate Status Button by p91paul](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/755/hibernate-status-button/). But you need a requirement, just install `polkitd-pkla` by running

```
sudo apt install polkitd-pkla
```

on terminal. (I found from comments)

## Solution 2

As mentioned as on extension's [GitHub page](https://github.com/arelange/gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status):

> ## Hibernation button does not show up, but systemctl hibernate works
>
> If you are running Ubuntu, try putting
>
> ```
> [Enable hibernate in upower]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
>
> [Enable hibernate in logind]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle->hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate->multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
> ResultActive=yes
> ```
>
> into /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla

So you can try this method. Open a terminal and run

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

and copy-paste this:

```
[Enable hibernate in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```